# Hadoop - @Override error for mappers and reducers

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, overriding, reduce

I've been working on a MapReduce program and I've hit a roadblock and need some help. I have a program that runs 3 jobs (job #2 gets ran 5 times within a for loop) and it seems like a few of my mappers and reducers are not properly defined. Upon compiling I keep getting "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype" errors.

Here's the basic structure of my program:

`Job 1:`

FirstMapper 
**No Reducer**

`Job 2:`

Second Mapper
First Reducer

`Job 3:`

Final Mapper
Final Reducer

And here's how I have my mappers and reducers defined:

```
public static class FirstMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, LongWritable, Vertex>  {
        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {}


public static class SecondMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Vertex, LongWritable, Vertex> {
        @Override
        public void map(long key, Vertex value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {}


public static class FirstReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, Vertex, LongWritable, Vertex> {
        @Override
        public void reduce(Long key, Iterable<Vertex> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {}


public static class FinalMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Vertex, LongWritable, LongWritable> {
        @Override
        public void map(Long key, Vertex value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {}


public static class FinalReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, LongWritable, LongWritable, LongWritable> {
        @Override
        public void reduce(Long key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {}
```

**FirstMapper** appears to be ok as it doesn't cause an error but the other 4 do and I can't figure out why because the method signatures look correct.  I initially thought maybe it was because of my custom **Vertex** class but it implements **Writable** so I'm not sure why this would be causing an issue. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keys need to implement the `WritableComparable` interface and match the type you specify in the classes `Mapper` and `Reducer` signature. For example in the second one you have:

`Mapper<LongWritable, Vertex, LongWritable, Vertex>`

But then in the `map` method you use `long`. This needs to match the types you specify in the signature, ie `LongWritable`. So the parameters of the second map need to look like:

`map(LongWritable key, Vertex value, Context context)`

All of the last four classes have this problem.

Comment: Thanks, just needed another set of eyes to find the issue haha. This fixed it.